# Wrap a view and view model to add cross-cutting concerns

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

In non-ui code I'm used to add decorators/wrappers around instances of interfaces to add cross-cutting concerns like logging, checking etc.

Now I'm looking for a way to do something similar for ui code, which is view-model first in my application.

An example:

I have a sample model like this

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
     // some properties
}
```

and a data template for it

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:SampleViewModel>
     <!-- some content -->
</DataTemplate>
```

In some cases I need to add a border around a view for a view model which can be animated to highlight the area for instance.

This border could be added to virtually every view, so adding the border to this specific data template is no option.

My initial approach was adding a wrapper view model like this:

```
public class BlinkingBorderWrapperViewModel
{
    public BlinkingBorderWrapperViewModel(IWantBeAbleToBlink innerVM)
    {
        InnerVM = innerVM;
    }

    public object InnerVM {get;private set;}

    // expose properties relevant for the blinking part
    // some may be retrieved via the interface `IWantBeAbleToBlink`
}
```

and a data template

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:BlinkingBorderWrapperViewModel}>
  <!-- draw the wrapping stuff -->
  <Border ...>
      <!-- include the wrapped vm -->
      <ContentControl Content={Binding Path=InnerVM} />
  <Border ...>
</DataTemplate>
```

The interface `IWantBeAbleToBlink` is used to exchange data with the wrapper (e.g. if it should blink right now) and as a tag to check if it should be wrapped.

This works so far for a single wrapper with these drawbacks:

- the view model needs to store the wrapped sub-viewmodels and thus looses type information (the wrapper can be no template due to data template restrictions).
- I have no clue how to add a second, third, ... wrapper in a way that is maintainable.
- I might add several wrappers, but this would have to be done from the view's side (i.e. in XAML and *not* from the view model)

**Is there a way to achieve this adding of cross-cutting concerns to view (models) that allows several aspects to be added and is usable with an view model first approach?**

Other stuff I might want to add:

- An anchor tag so the view (model) can be navigated to
- A wrapper logging mouse moves
- A wrapper for enabling/disabling
- ...

## from the comments:

### Leaking UI logic?

In my opinion the view model should be able to express the need to "be highlighted". This could be done by blinking, a change in the background, change in font-size or whatever the view implements.

Since the view model should not care how this is done (and the way the highlighting is performed  should be changeable without having a need to adjust the view model), I'd like just to provide an interface better named `IWantToBeAbleToBeHighlighted` (instead of `IWantBeAbleToBlink`) with maybe just a single switch.

The concrete properties exposed to the view (blink frequence, or new font size or new background color) should be included in the wrapper view model.

Comment: You're leaking UI logic into your view model.  Why should something be blinking?  Probably some aspect of the state of the view model. Express this state in a bindable property, then use facilities in the UI (whatever they may be; codebehind, user controls, etc) to add the blinky stuff.

Comment: @ Will I think you got me wring. Please see my answer at the bottom of the question. My primary concern is to "add" this extra stuff and not include this to the other properties. Also see the other wrappers I have in mind like the "mouse moves over control logger".

Comment: I think Will is spot on. The things you describe (font size, background color, etc.) are presentation properties. Ideally, your view models shouldn't concern themselves with how to present their data, which is what you're doing by pushing those types of properties into your view models. Let your view dictate how to interpret your view model's data and provide the desired presentation from it. Decompose your view into reusable parts using Blend behaviors, value converters, and (if needed) custom controls that expose dependency properties on them for presentation options you want configurable.

Comment: For example you can create a Blend behavior that logs the mouse events. Wrap your view model element in a ContentControl to provide an anchor for your behaviors. In the behavior, the VisualTreeHelper can get the root visual created by your DataTemplate. You can then do things such as create a storyboard for your blink effect and apply it to your content. Blink frequency, color, etc. can be set by dependency properties defined on the behavior. If you need to change the view based on some view model property, bind the VM property to the DP on your behavior and use a value converter if necessary.

Comment: I understand.  But your whole issue is based on the fact that this pattern is deeply flawed.  But, if you still want to go down this route, you'll need to investigate wrapping your view model in a *single* wrapper that proxies the wrapped view model and works with the WPF binding system.  I've done this before, and it works well, but it's definitely NOT for the faint of heart.  We're talking about wrapping entire object graphs with types that implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider and DynamicMetaObject. Collections are a lovely complication to this, not including the attached property system...

Comment: The single wrapper on which you can hang UI support is the key--and that wrapper must appear to the UI as the type itself.  Using poco wrappers and interfaces won't work well.  WPF binding logic is deeply tied to the types involved, so the proxy has to pretend to be the type that is wrapped in order to provide the most seamless experience in design.  Luckily the binding system respects type descriptors of many types (such as the IDynamicMetaObjectProviders), which gives you an in.

Comment: @Mvromer To stick to the "mouse click logging" case: If I get you right, I'd have to adjust every `ContentControl` to enable logging for all view models? In the final version I think there will be  more than 1000 `ContentControl`s. And if I want to add another aspect like the highlighting/blinking stuff, I'll have to touch all of them again?

Comment: @Will Why does the wrapper have to expose all the properties? Is it not possible to expose the wrapped view model as a single property like in my wrapper view? Can you provide some sample code for your approach?